# Why was Gas Interconnector Greece-Bulgaria delayed so much?

Tags: energy-policy, gas, energy-independence, bulgaria

[Greece-Bulgaria gas interconnector startup is now set for July 2022](https://www.spglobal.com/platts/en/market-insights/latest-news/natural-gas/052721-greece-bulgaria-gas-interconnector-startup-now-set-for-july-2022-developer) after multiple delays:

> The Interconnector Greece-Bulgaria, or IGB, -- part of
> the much-heralded Southern Gas Corridor -- **has been delayed several
> times**, most recently due to the coronavirus pandemic.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_Interconnector_Greece-Bulgaria) mentions that this project was supposed to start back in 2014 (so, way before the COVID and [what seems to be Russian generated gas crisis in EU](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2022/jan/12/russia-europe-gas-crisis-international-energy-agency-boss))

> (..)  it will achieve real diversification of sources of supply of
> natural gas to Bulgaria. (..) The pipeline was expected to be put in
> operation **in December 2014**.

Why has a very important (energy security-related) project like this been delayed so much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between the signing of the MOU and the planned completion of the work came the Eurozone debt crisis, which affected Greece significantly.

Also, projects like this tend to take longer than "planned" in Europe. People use best-case assumptions to argue for their project, then the lowest bidder is selected, and suddenly someone finds an endangered fowl in a wetlands. By the time that is litigated, the public no longer remembers what they agreed to do and demand public participation in the decision process.